# Premiere Elements: alternating between parallel video tracks

Tags: multi-camera, premiere-elements

say I would be filming same thing with multiple (3-4) cameras.

What's the easiest way to be able to make a final video alternating between them at arbitrary points?

I know I can split the clips and put them to one track, but if I decide it doesn't look good its a major PITA to rework. I'd just prefer to have them all on different tracks and just decide which one is playing at that point in time.

Sorry, I'm complete noob at premiere.